# Xamarin.Android Set backgroundimage in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I cant find a good example how to code a backgroundimage with C# code

In my project i needed to create a folder called drawable. If this is a factor.

I dont know which one to use and how to use it.

Image.

[image]

Code i have now. that i want to change to image.

[image]

Comment: you can do something like: `android:background="@drawable/imageName"` in the layout xml file

Comment: drawable should be a folder INSIDE of Resources

Comment: Ashish Srivastava
Yes but in this action i need the answer from a C# perspective

Comment: Jason 
Thanks i have moved it. 
Do you know how to implement the background with C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see, you have two options `SetBackgroundDrawable` and `SetBackgroundResource`.

If you don't need to modify the drawable before assigning it, then the easiest way is to use `SetBackgroundResource`. Since you called your drawable `noconnection` then it will have its Id generated as `Resource.Drawable.noconnection`. So combining those two you get:

```
mainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.noconnection);
```

If you need to load the drawable, you should probably use `ContextCompat` to load it like:

```
var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this, Resource.Drawable.noconnection);

// do whatever with drawable
// like tinting:
DrawableCompat.SetTint(drawable, someTintColor);

mainLinearLayout.SetBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks alot =)
Can you give an exampel how to modifie with Drawable?